# I can't run my app in Redmi Note3 from Android Studio 2.3

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow

The device is detecting well, and also enabled permission to install from other sources in device settings, But after gradle build done at the installation time I am getting below error only in Redmi Note 3:

```
Installation failed with message Failed to establish
```

Refer to Image below
[image] session
MI Version : MIUI 8.1.1.0, In previous version is working fine I using same device to run the apps from Android Studio. After updating to Versions 8.1.1.0 only this issue occurs

Comment: Can you share your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: Hi, on http://android.stackexchange.com please, don't ask about Android development, publishing, or marketing questions. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com is a good place for your question. Then your question should be migrated or deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow these steps:

1. Go to Build > Clean Project
2. File > Invalidate caches/Restart > Invalidate and Restart

This should work.

P.S. Also CLEAR CACHE and CLEAR DATA of the app if its already installed on your android device.